# No MongoDB option in Pentaho

Tags: mongodb, pentaho

I recently pulled down Pentaho Data Integration from SourceForge

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/

and am trying to get it to connect to MongoDB. Every tutorial I find assumes that the option is availabe under Big Data --> MongoDB but I am not seeing the option.

[image]

I tried to utilize New --> Data Connection as well but that option is disabled.

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly as I cannot seem to find any documentation regarding this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two different issues here. The "New -> Data Connection..." problem is a bug: http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-14307

The MongoDB problem is likely an issue with the Karaf container (new in 6.0). Try shutting down PDI and deleting the contents of data-integration/system/karaf/data1/ then restarting. That will clear the Karaf cache and cause everything to be freshly loaded when starting up again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I checked under data-integration/system/karaf/ and the only data directory i have is named "data" which contains a README file.

Comment: I just pulled down version 5.4.0.1 and I'm not seeing the option in there either. Is the Mongo option just not available for the free version?

Comment: Sounds like your Karaf isn't starting at all. If you're on Windows try running SpoonConsole.bat so you can get console output at startup. Or on Linux/Mac run spoon.sh from a terminal.  You should see some errors related to Karaf startup, If you update your post with that info I can take a look.

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: You got it. SpoonConsole.bat showed that Karaf was unable to create the appropriate directories. I ran the file with Admin privileges and the mongo option appeared. Thank you for your help!